# How to decorate an instance with code-blocks and accessing/using the variables of the instance?

Tags: python, oop, instance, decorator, wrapper

I try to build a decorator for methods of instances (not classes) that flexibly puts code blocks in front and/or behind the method (and not affect other instances). Up to my code below works:

```
def Decorate(func, before = None, after = None): 
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs): 
        if before: before() # code block insert
        result = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        if after: after() # code block insert
        return result 
    return wrap 
  
class Test():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def put(self, prefix):
        print(prefix, self.name)

a = Test('me')

def Before():
    print('before')

def After():
    print('after')

a.put = Decorate(a.put, Before, After)
a.put('it is')
```

How can I extend the code blocks accessing/using variables and methods of the instance? A code example for this would look like this:

```
def Before():
    print('before')
    print(self.name)
    self.any_method(any_argument) # just an example!
```

I already tried several things without success. And I already struggle to access the instance values directly in the wrapper:

```
def Decorate(func, before = None, after = None): 
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if before: before() # code block insert

        print(self.name) # --> even this DOES NOT WORK!

        result = func(self, *args, **kwargs) 
        if after: after() # code block insert
        return result 
    return wrap
```

Here `print(self.name)` throws an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`. So it looks like that I am far away in using the same comment in one of the code blocks (`Before()` & `After()`) below.

One addition: The approach works when I add a method to the instance:
This method is in the class (so for working with strings and exec, but that enables to deliver the name as string or the function itself):

```
    def addMethod(self, method, givenName = ''):
        print('add')
        if givenName == '': 
            N = method.__name__
        else: 
            N = givenName
        self._methods.append(N)
        exec('self.' + N + ' = ' + method.__name__ + '.__get__(self)')
```

The code in the main part looks like this:

```
def x(self):
    print('hello,', self.name)

a.addMethod(x)
a.x()
```

Any solution is appreciated and many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import wraps


def Decorate(func, before = None, after = None):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs): 
        if before: before() # code block insert
        result = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        if after: after() # code block insert
        return result 
    return wrap

def Before():
    print('before')

def After():
    print('after')

class Test():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def put(self, prefix):
        print(prefix, self.name)
    
    put = Decorate(put, Before, After)

a = Test('me')
a.put("pre")
```

You could execute your decorator inside your class. In your `wrap`, pass whatever you get to `func` by `(*args, **kwargs)`. `self` is still the first argument implicitly in `args`.

**Edit**: Code related concerns from comments

---

```
from functools import wraps


def Before(t):
    print('before')
    print(t.name)


def After(t):
    print('after')
    print(t.name)


def Decorate(func, before = None, after = None):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs): 
        if before: before(args[0]) # code block insert
        result = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        if after: after(args[0]) # code block insert
        return result 
    return wrap

class Test():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def put(self, prefix):
        print(prefix, self.name)

    put = Decorate(put, Before, After)


a = Test('me')
a.put("pre")
```

Comment: That worked anyway. The problem is, to add references including `self...` into `before()` and `after()` like this: ```def Before(): print(self.name)``` This causes an error and the extension of the method like that is what I need!

Comment: @Ulrich You could have ``def Before(t): print(t.name)``.  You need pass a instance of ``Test`` to ``Before``. Now when you call it, it need to use that instance by ``if before: before(args[0])``

Comment: Hi Ke, nope does not work. I added my current state of code to your answer.

Comment: Use ``args[0]`` as your function argument which is the instance, not ``*args, **kwargs``

Comment: Nope! Still not working. Could you paste your proposal as a whole? Would do me a great favour with that! In this line: `if before: before(args[0]) # code block insert` I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`...

Comment: Sure, will do. However, I notice you call ``a.put = Decorate(...)`` outside of your class definition. By your way, ``a.put`` become a raw function instead of a method. Also, when you construct other instance, you need re-decorate each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227609/discussion-between-ke-zhang-and-ulrich).